# Flutter doctor search location

Tags: linux, flutter, archlinux, manjaro

Where does flutter doctor command look for Android Studio, Visual Studio Code etc. Mine is not detecting VSCode even if I have installed it.

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.2.1, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.3)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.4)
[!] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2019.1)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories
```

I don't use Intellij with flutter, so I can simply ignore that warning.

I'm on Manjaro i3 and tried installing both VSCode open source (from Arch Community Repository) and MS branded version (from Arch User Repository) though pacman.

Answer (score 0):

You can add VS Code to your PATH,then it will be solved.

Launch VS Code.

Open the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P) and type 'shell command' to find the Shell Command:

Install 'code' command in PATH command.